# Unable to write manifest, System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When I try to compile my program on Visual Studio 2010 I get this error:

> "Unable to write manifest
>   'obj\x86\Debug\WindowsApplication3.exe.manifest'. Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

It seems that this error occurs quite randomly. I got it for the first time some weeks ago and I had to restore Windows to solve the problem. Then I got the same error this morning and this time I had to delete the Debug folder. Finally, two hours later, same error again and none of the two previous solutions are working.

Comment: Along with the exception do you get a stacktrace (or is it logged anywhere?)

Comment: Nothing, just this message on the Error list window.

Comment: Does the window have a 'Details' button?

Comment: As a side note, restoring windows to fix an `OutOfMemoryException` is not actually a solution, and nor is deleting the `Debug` folder. Although you didn't see the error afterwards, those actions were *not* the real reason.

Comment: No 'Details' button on the Error list window. And of course restoring Windows or deleting the Debug folder are not the best things to do, I tried other solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: Have you got any plugins/extensions installed in VS2010?

Comment: How big is your solution? Do you have a lot of resources or custom compile tools included?